# Tiling a small image into a bigger one with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Let's say I have an image of 200x200 pixels. I'd like a 800x800 pixels version where I basically duplicate the 200x200 image and fill the 800x800 image with(Tile the smaller image into the bigger one).

How would you go to do that in openCV? It seems straight-forward, but I don't know how to either create another cv::Mat with the same type as the pattern, but with a bigger size(Canvas size) or if it's possible to take the original 200x200 pixels image and increase it's rows and cols then simply use a loop to paste the corner unto the rest of the image.

I'm using openCV 2.3 btw. I've done quite some processing on images with fixed dimensions, but I'm kind of clueless when it comes to increasing the dimensions of the matrix.

Comment: Hi, are you asking about resizing the image to bigger size or tiling small image together to make bigger one ?

Comment: I ask for tiling the smaller image into a larger(Initially empty) version.

Comment: then you got the answer below from karl.

Comment: Here is an answer in Python OpenCV: [In python, using the cv2 library; how can I tile one image into a second image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67628430/13552470)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tile](https://techtutorialsx.com/2020/02/23/python-opencv-image-tiling/) function:

```
def tile_image(tile, height, width):      
  x_count = int(width / tile.shape[0]) + 1
  y_count = int(height / tile.shape[1]) + 1

  tiled = np.tile(tile, (y_count, x_count, 1))

  return tiled[0:height, 0:width]
```

Comment: You suggest `cv::repeat` but show an example using `np.tile`, in Python, not C++…

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can just do something like this:

```
cvx::Mat CreateLargeImage(const cvx::Mat& small, int new_rows, int new_cols) {
  // Create a Mat of the desired size, the mat may also be created by resizing of the smaller one.
  cvx::Mat result(new_rows, new_cols, 16);
  const int sm_rows = small.rows;
  const int sm_cols = small.cols;
  for (int r = 0; r < result.rows; ++r) {
    for (int c = 0; c < result.cols; ++c) {
        // use mod operation to effectively repeat the small Mat to the desired size.
        result.at<cvx::Vec3b>(r, c)[0] =
            small.at<cvx::Vec3b>(r % sm_rows, c % sm_cols)[0];
        result.at<cvx::Vec3b>(r, c)[1] =
            small.at<cvx::Vec3b>(r % sm_rows, c % sm_cols)[1];
        result.at<cvx::Vec3b>(r, c)[2] =
            small.at<cvx::Vec3b>(r % sm_rows, c % sm_cols)[2];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Or you may use openCV's [repeat function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga496c3860f3ac44c40b48811333cfda2d). e.g,

in Python

```
import cv2
...
duplicated = cv2.repeat(original, 4, 4)
```

in C++

```
 cv::Mat original= cv::imread("./benz.jpeg");
 cv::Mat duplicated;

 cv::repeat(original, 4, 4, duplicated);
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI- The blog in @karlphillip's response, the basic idea is to use `cvSetImageROI` and `cvResetImageROI`.  Both are C APIs.

In later versions, v2.4 and 3.x for example, one can define a `Rect` with the desired location and dimensions and refer to the desired section as `img(rect)`.

Example in C API (functional style):

```
cvSetImageROI(new_img, cvRect(tlx, tly, width, height);
cvCopy(old_img, new_img);
cvResetImageROI(new_img);
```

In the C++ API using classes:

```
Mat roi(new_img, Rect(tlx, tly, width, height));
roi = old_img;    // or old_img.clone()
```

Another way in C++ (copies over the image):

```
old_img.copyTo(new_img(Rect(tlx, tly, width, height)))
```